# Powershell RegEx - Insert string using -replace with ?=

Tags: regex, powershell

Here's my string:

```
 $s = "Here.is.my.string"
```

I want to insert ".NEW" into $s to make it look like this:

```
 "Here.is.my.NEW.string"
```

What I don't understand is while this works:

```
$s -ireplace '(?=\.[a-z]+$)',".NEW"    yields: "Here.is.my.NEW.string"
```

This doesn't:

```
 $s -ireplace '(?=\..+$)',".NEW"       yields: "Here.NEW.is.NEW.my.NEW.string"
```

Why can't . stands in for [a-z]?

Comment: Because "." also matches "." - i.e. it matches all characters, so your lookahead matches every . followed by a word. The first example is anchored such that it matches only a . followed by the last word.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you can use [www.regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com/#python) to test your regex, and it'll even explain things for you. (make sure it's set to python for best results for PowerShell, and you probably want to set the modifiers 'gm' for it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't `.` stand in for `[a-z]`?

The dot matches a single character (except newline), without caring what that character is. Using `[a-z]` specifically matches a single character in the range between `a` and `z`.

---

With using your second Lookahead example, it first matches a literal dot `.` and then looks for any character except newline sequence (`1`or more times), so it begins matching at the first dot and repeats itself at every dot until the end of the string. (*Assuming your doing a global replacement*). Your first Lookahead example, matches a literal dot `.` and any character of `a` to `z` (`1` or more times) at the end of the string.

So by using the following regular expression:

```
(?=\..+$)
```

Without consuming characters in the string it asserts before each dot until the end of the string.

```
Here .is .my .string
    ^   ^   ^
```

<kbd>[See regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/sO1dX2)</kbd>

Where as your first Lookahead asserts at the last dot `.` which is followed by characters of `a` to `z` that are anchored at the end of your string.

```
Here.is.my .string
          ^ 
            ^^^^^^ Any character of 'a' to 'z' (1 or more times)
```

<kbd>[See regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/nT0tB7)</kbd>